# SpringBoot KafkaConsumer not consuming from beginning

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot kafka consumer that is configured with `auto.offset.reset=earliest` for a specific consumer group ID. I want the consumer consumer from beginning whenever the application is restarted. I don't see this happening. It consumes from beginning when I change the offset and when I restart the app, it starts from latest again. Why is spring overriding my `auto.offset.reset=earliest` setting?

```
  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, configuration.getBrokers());
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, configuration.getKafkaInputTopic() + "_id");
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put("ssl.truststore.location", configuration.getKafkaSslTrustStore());
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    config.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
    config.put("sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-512");
```

```
@Service
@Getter
@Slf4j
public class KafkaConsumerService {

  private final Map<String, Set<String>> fleetVinsMap = new HashMap<>();

  @KafkaListener(topics = "${app.conf.source.kafka.topic}",
      containerFactory = "heartbeatKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
  public void consume(String message) {
  ...
  }
```

Above is my consumerFactory and the consumer service. Is there anything else I should setup?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? What would be the point of always reading already consumed messages? The `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` only says that you want to read messages from the start, instead of only new ones **when the consumer group is connected for the first time**. Always re-reading already consumed messages sounds weird/wrong.

Comment: My application loses state every time it is restarted. The topic I have is not heavy and has a updates once a day. So I want to consume from that topic whenever there is an update and of course be able to consume from beginning whenever I want to. @ŠimonKocúrek
Also, I'm not consuming all messages "always", only when my app restarts.

Answer (score 1):

As [@Šimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5521670/%C5%A0imon-koc%C3%BArek) has introduced, the offset of a consumer in a ConsumerGroup is managed by the Kafka Broker and is thus resilient to application refreshes. This is generally the preferred way of consuming messages, as we do not want to read messages twice.

If you want to consume the same messages anyway (for example in a Dev environment), start a new consumer group and set the property:

```
config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
```

This will turn off the consumer's auto commit strategy and require you to manually commit the message offset with commitAsync() or commitSync(). If no commit is made, no offset is stored in the Kafka Broker.